# Django Template Language doesn't work in one of my template files

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

The "<% %>" template notation to use JavaScript seems to work fine. However, when I try to use the {% %} template notation to use Python (I want to be able to access the user variable to check to see if the user "is_staff" or not), "{% if user.is_authenticated %}" simply shows up as plain text when the page is loaded. How can I get the Django template language to work in this template? (It works fine in my main template, index.html. However, I want to use it here in month-day.html that gets loaded into index.html. I want to only show certain events based on whether or not the user is a staff member or not.)

```
    <div class="cal-month-day <%= cls %> <% if (events.length == 0) {%>cal-month-day-slash<% } %>">
        <span class="pull-left" data-cal-date="<%=  data_day %>"  data-cal-view="day" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="<%= tooltip %>"><%= day %></span>

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <% if (events.length > 0) {%>
            <div class="events-list">

                <% _.each(events, function(event){ %>
                <% if (event.class == "event-success") {%>
                    <a href="<%= event.url %>" data-event-id="<%= event.id %>" data-event-class="<%= event.class %>"
                       class="pull-right event <%= event.class %>  event<%= event.id %>" rel="tooltip"
                       data-original-title="<%= event.title %>" data-event-start="<%= event.start %>" data-event-end="<%= event.end %>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<%= event.title %>"></a>
                <% } %>
                <% }); %>


        </div>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

The code for the entire application can be seen here: https://github.com/Glchriste/Tutoring-Application

Comment: You'll need at least to explain what that "Javascript template" syntax is, and it would be helpful to know which of the many, many templates in this project this file is from (and which view is rendering it).

Comment: `<%` isn't for Javascript nor Python, it lets you expose variables defined by the Django Python view code.  One of your views has the 'form' variable, which is now available in the corresponding template.  I think `user` is automatically exported in the Django machinery.

Comment: Ah, ok. I misunderstood the "<%" notation. I will look into it with this info, thank you.